# Add html in a variable

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to add a html tag `<br>` in a variable (marked below), but when page is rendered it's recognised as plain text. I'm not sure where I went wrong.

P.S. Not sure if it matters: I'm using Cakephp. It is a variable in a custom helper class.

```
App::uses('AppHelper', 'View/Helper');

class ComaHelper extends AppHelper {
    public $helpers = array('Time');

    public function coma($array, $name) {
        $prefix = ''; 
        $result = '';
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) { 

            $result .= $prefix . $value;

            if ($name == 'condition') { 
                $prefix = ', <br>'; // it's shown as plain text on the page
            } else { 
                $prefix = ', '; 
            }
        } 
        return $result;
    } 
}
```

The page:

```
<?php echo h($this->Coma->coma($post['Condition'], 'condition')); ?>
```

Comment: check the source code if the tag is escaped.

Comment: Indeed it is. gmponos points out in the answer below that I shouldn't wrap the output with h(). Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your view with the `h()` function you are using:

This function is a convenience method for htmlspecialchars

http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/function-h.html

Check the result of:

```
<?= h('<br>') ?>;
```